# code first auto gen proxy class navigation and collection properties are null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3

For all of my POCOs, the navigation and collection properties are all null.

Let me provide some background. I have a complex code first project using EF 4.3.1. Proxy generation was disabled. Collection and navigation properties were managed manually.

I'm now enabling proxy creation and lazy loading. When debugging, I can see that my entity (which is cast to my known POCO type) is now actually an auto generated proxy class. So far so good.

Now, when I look at my navigation properties, they are null. Similarly, my collection properties are null.

Using reflection, I can see that the proxy class HAS overridden my navigation and collection properties.

All navigation and collection properties are virtual. e.g:

```
public virtual NavigationType NavigationName { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<CollectionType> CollectionName { get; set; }
```

Also, all tables are initialised as such:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TEntity>()
.Map(m =>
{
    m.MapInheritedProperties();
    m.ToTable("TableName");
});
```

I can also confirm that the database is generated as expected. Foreign keys are all present and are associated with the expected fields.

Why are they null? How can I diagnose this further?

Comment: Are these collection properties marked as `virtual` in your class?

Comment: Have a look at the requirements - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/dd468057(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @alex. Yes they are virtual.

Comment: @devdigital My setup meets all of the requirements.

Comment: Where do you actually define the relationships using the fluent API or otherwise?

Comment: @devdigital The relationships are inferred by EF. Just like the NerdDinner examples.

Comment: Can you show your querying code, context etc?

Comment: Are you inspecting the collection before you've attempted to access it programmatically?  Try doing `var col = entity.CollectionName.ToList();`  and inspect that instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I diagnose this further?

You could check for example if the entities you are inspecting are attached to the context by looking into the change tracker's `context.ChangeTracker.Entries()` collection.

It's well possible that you have a dynamic proxy with all navigation properties being `null`, for example:

```
Entity entity = context.Entities.Create();
```

`entity` will be a proxy, but `NavigationName` and `CollectionName` will be `null` and they will stay `null` even when you access these properties (leading to `NullReferenceException`s). This will only change when you attach the entity:

```
context.Entities.Attach(entity);
```

If you access the properties now lazy loading should run. `NavigationName` *can* stay `null` if there is no related entity in the database, but the collection `CollectionName` should never be `null` after attaching and accessing it. If there are no related entities in the DB the result should be an empty collection, but not `null`.

Comment: Interesting. The path I'm taking is as you say. It use .Create() but don't .Attach(..) the entity until I'm ready to commit. I'll investigate now.

Comment: Nail on the head. I've not implemented initialisation for when the entities are first created. Ta very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the relationships between entities using modelbuilder:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2011/05/04/entity-framework-code-first-tutorial-supplement-what-is-going-on-in-a-fluent-api-call.aspx